# Protractor - timeouts oon browser.wait(ExpectedCondition)

Tags: javascript, exception, selenium, webdriver, protractor

Have stuck on a problem with my tests stability.
Problem is that sometimes `Wait timed out after` occurs on waiting for some element.

Here it's how I am waiting:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.position.value), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element position was not clickable ');
```

Issue appears on many EC waits in many test case. The biggest problem is that this issue is totally random !

Example test case:

```
it('displays page of user', function () {
    var positionUsersTableThirdRow = usersPage.thirdRowPosition.getText();
    var idUsersTableThirdRow = usersPage.thirdRowId.getText();
    var emailUsersTableThirdRow = usersPage.thirdRowEmail.getText();
    clickWithWait(usersPage.thirdRow);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.position.value), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element position was not clickable ');
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.id), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element id was not clickable ');
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.email), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element email was not clickable ');
    expect(userDetailsPage.position.value.getText()).toEqual(positionUsersTableThirdRow);
    expect(userDetailsPage.id.getText()).toEqual(idUsersTableThirdRow);
    expect(userDetailsPage.email.getText()).toEqual(emailUsersTableThirdRow);
});
```

framework: jasmine2

page is developed in backbone.js

wait timeout is defined to 20000

chromedriver: 2.19

protractor : Version 2.5.0

Comment: Which framework are you using? Jasmine or Mocha???

Comment: Is your webpage angular based? Whats the `WAIT_TIMEOUT` value you have mentioned in the tests? And does your tests fail even though the elements are visible on the DOM?

Comment: updated topic, no idea if elements are visible on DOM or not, could be possible that framework wait for something what disappeared already ?

Comment: This could be a problem with some previous steps, that "make" this element clickeable in the form. For example element becomes clickeable only when all fields are correctly filled etc. Do you have prinskrins of erroneous forms ? Did you verify these printskrins ? In many cases the error is obvious at first glance when you see the printskrin.

Comment: Nope, it can not be problem you have mentioned cause even when wait is on the first line of test then is timing out. Moreover button state do not depend on any previous action, it is active all the time.

Comment: please post your p-tor version, chromedriver version.